# SOCKET connection: the program does not recognize the connect method

Tags: c++, sockets, qt6

I'm working on a project in Qt Creator 6.3 and I'm programming it in C++. The program uses a GUI, threads and works like a client.
I need to make a TCP/IP connection using a socket to connect to the server. I have seen several tutorials and in all of them they use the connect function to connect to the server. In all tutorials, this function is used in the main.cpp.

The problem is that I need to make this conection in the GUI and not in the main.cpp. But, when I try to use the connect method the program confuses this method with the connect method that uses slots and signals as an argument. Is there a way to tell the program which connect I want to use?
I need to make the connection in the GUI because I have threads that need to receive data from the socket and save it in variables that are from the GUI.
I need something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    RadarGUI w;  //this is the GUI
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

In radargui.cpp a function that makes the connections with the socket

```
void RadarGUI::conectar_servidor(){

    std::string ip= "127.0.0.1"; 
    int port=2020;              

    //winsock
    WSAData data;
    WORD version= MAKEWORD(2,2);
    int wsResultado= WSAStartup(version, &data);

    if (wsResultado != 0){
        printf("fallo inicializacion de winsock del cliente");
    }

    //socket
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if (sock== INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("fallo creacion del socket del cliente");
        WSACleanup();
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    //connect to server, HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    int conectarResultado = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint)); //the program think 
                                                   //that this function needs signal and slot

    if (conectarResultado != SOCKET_ERROR){
        printf("el cliente no pudo conectarse al servidor");
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
    }
}
```

The error related to the connect method:

```
No matching member function for call to 'connect'

candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'SOCKET' (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'const QObject *' for 1st argument
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are directly using POSIX sockets instead of Qt's [`QTcpSocket`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcpsocket.html)  class?

Comment: If you insist on using the POSIX socket APIs then use `::connect` otherwise the compiler will probably try to resolve `connect` to one of the `QObject::connect` overloads.

Comment: Echoing @UnholySheep's comment: that entire mess of code is a less featureful version of `QTcpSocket *sock = new QTcpSocket; sock->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 2020);`